# Proving the set identity $(X \cup Y) = X + Y - (X \cap Y)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to know if the identity $(X \cup Y) = X + Y - (X \cap Y)$ holds true for any set X and Y? Here, X + Y means all elements in X and Y including repeated elements.

Comment: Better to say that $n(X \cup Y) = n(X) + n(Y) - n(X \cap Y)$.

Comment: You need to be precise about how you model sets with repetition, and then how you define the set operations, and the meaning of equality. Before you do that, the question is too vague (though certainly there is a grain of truth to it).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite literally true, because in set theory there is no such thing as "repeated elements". So $+$ becomes just $\cup$, in which case there is no unique reading to the statement (do you take $\cup$ before $-$ or after?) and that makes the statement a bit vague.

However you can change it slightly and then it is true: $$X\cup Y=X\cup(Y-(X\cap Y))$$

If you want to talk about finite sets, then cardinal arithmetic makes this statement true, namely: $$|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|$$
But the finiteness assumption is somewhat necessary here, since subtraction is not well-defined for infinite sets.

Comment: But $|X|+|Y|=|X\cup Y|+|X\cap Y|$ for arbitrary sets $X,Y$ holds in ZF, right? And the same goes for the general in-and-out formula, written without minus signs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.